# How to locate origin of world frame in Rviz?

Tags: rviz, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am currently trying to visualize the world pose of my robot by publishing a poseStamped message to Rviz.
I can see the axes fine but I want to know where the **origin of the world frame in Rviz** is.

Below is an image of the issue, the world frame is on the corner to the right wall of where the person is sitting,
clearly the view in which Rviz opens up is not the origin. Hence, How can I find Rviz's origin ?

Thanks !

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/293098/how-to-locate-origin-of-world-frame-in-rviz-?/) by [malharjajoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33038/malharjajoo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2018-06-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as RViz has a world frame, it's probably at `0, 0, 0`. That would be in the centre of the grid you see rendered in your screenshot.

You can visualise it by adding an `Axes` display to your configuration.

But note:

1. the name `world` has no special significance to RViz
2. the 'root' of your transform tree will be whatever you make it. It will depend on the transform broadcasters that you have running. There is no 'always present' frame called `world`

If you're using TF (and I believe you are), it would probably be more informative to add a TF display to your configuration. That would immediately show you how things (ie: frames) are related.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2